# Incorrect number of questions shown on network profile

Tags: bug

On my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4576460/nateowami?tab=accounts) it shows that I have asked 0 questions on StackOverflow. In reality, I have asked 1 and it was quite some time ago. You can see this on [my StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3714913/nateowami?tab=questions).

[image]
Pardon the lack of a drop-shadow. It's guaranteed hand-drawn

Is there a weird explanation for this, or is it what it looks like, a bug?

Comment: It's a feature.

Comment: By the way, it says you have asked 1 question**S** on Arduino.

Comment: @Pang See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36933, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746.